# jQuery replace image with drag & drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a small drag & drop feature on my site and I got the drag & drop function working fine. Users can drag and drop a image to the `.vote` container, but when someone wants to replace they're previous dropped image with another image, it just adds it so then there are two images in the `.vote` container.

The idea is that when someone drops an image into the `#container` and then later drops another image in it that the first image goes back into the `#drag` container. But I can't figure out what kind of function I could use.

This is the code I use for the drag & drop.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    addElements();
    $(function () {
        $(".vote, #drag").sortable({
            connectWith: ".vote , #drag",
            cursor: "move"
        }).disableSelection();
    });

    function addElements() {
        $(".vote, #drag").append();
    }

});
```

So the question is, how do I check if there's all ready an image present in the `.vote` div. And if there's already an image how do I move that image back to the `#drag` container?

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle for your code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nkLtm/ there's the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

To check if there are already images in the container, you can use two kinds of functions.

A `.children()` call, which gives you all elements contained in `.vote` or `.find('img')` which returns images contained in `.vote`.

Answer (score 0):

in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/LSZD6/1/) probably there is a solution to your problems.
On left sisde there are some images that are draggable on the area on right side.
"When someone drops an image into the #container and then later drops another image in it  the first image goes back into the #drag container".
All jQuery code you need is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.dr').on("dragstart", function (event) {
              var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
              dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
            });

        $('#container').on("dragenter dragover drop", function (event) {    
           event.preventDefault();
           if (event.type === 'drop') {
              var old=$(this).find('.dr').detach()
              old.appendTo('#drag').removeAttr('style')
              var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text',$(this).attr('id'));
              de=$('#'+data).detach();
              de.css({'position':'absolute','top':0+'px','left':0+'px'}).appendTo($(this)); 
           };
       });
})
</script>
```